# How to run a file of google ranking in node.js

Tags: windows, node.js, google-ranking

I am newbie to Node.js and I have downloaded the **[google ranking](https://github.com/newleafdigital/nodejs-google-ranking)** from github. When i try to run a file **example.js**, its giving me the error **"Cannot find module 'jscrape'"**.

I even tried to install the jscrape module but its giving me error.

I found dependencies in package.json file as follows

```
   {
  "author": "Ben Buckman <ben@newleafdigital.com> (http://newleafdigital.com/)",
  "name": "google-ranking",
  "description": "Fetch the Google search ranking for a phrase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/newleafdigital/nodejs-google-ranking",
  "repository": {
    "url": "git@github.com:newleafdigital/nodejs-google-ranking.git"
  },
  "main": "google-ranking.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "jscrape": "0.0.4",
    "async": "~0.1.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "*"
  }
  "scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm install jscrape"
}
}
```

As i am very new to node.js, Can anyone please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend visiting the actual page http://nodejs.org/ as this provides a lot of information on downloading, installing and general how to use. Along with a vast amount of documentation.

Also I am sure jScrape is a piece of software built to be used by Node. With this kind of software (Other examples include WebSockets.IO, Express) they have to be downloaded and installed using Node.